# Integrating custom map markers and marker filters into a mapbox map

Tags: javascript, html, json, mapbox, geojson

I'm developing a map using mapbox an have run into a road block. I am trying to use custom markers and have buttons in the map to filter my markers so only certain markers will show depending on which button is active. The problem is I seem to be able to get one OR the other to work and not both. I can have a map with custom markers but no filters or a map with built in markers and working filters. I know almost no code beyond HTML and have been developing the map following mapboxes examples. If someone can take a look at this and let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it I would greatly appreciate it.

These are the two examples I am following:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markers-with-multiple-filters/
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-marker/

This is my code with working Icons and no working filter(I removed about 10 markers since it was the same code):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Custom marker icons</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.6/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.6/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.menu-ui {
  background:#A2A19F;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:50px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-110px;
  z-index:1;
  border-radius:3px;
  width:auto;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  }
  .menu-ui a {
    font-size:22px;
    color:#fff;
    display:table-cell;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    text-align:center;
    }
    .menu-ui a:first-child {
      border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
      }
    .menu-ui a:last-child {
      border:none;
      border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
      }
    .menu-ui a:hover {
      background:#f8f8f8;
      color:#404040;
      }
    .menu-ui a.active,
    .menu-ui a.active:hover {
      background:#DB3E3A;
      color:#FFF;
      }
  
.popup {
  text-align:center;
  }
.popup .slideshow .image        { display:none; }
.popup .slideshow .image.active { display:block; }
.popup .slideshow img {
  width:100%;
  }
.popup .slideshow .caption {
  background:#eee;
  padding:10px;
  }
.popup .cycle {
  padding:10px 0 20px;
  }
  .popup .cycle a.prev { float:left; }
  .popup .cycle a.next { float:right; }

</style>
<nav class='menu-ui'>
  <a href='#' class='active' data-filter='Development'>Development</a>
  <a href='#' data-filter='Land'>Land</a>

</nav>

<div id='map'></div>
<!-- jQuery is required for this example. -->
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoib21uaXVzbm93IiwiYSI6ImFlZ0pNSXMifQ.VNyOy9GaRZ1cAS2nDTp3tw';
var southWest = L.latLng(21.284438,-131.265625),
    northEast = L.latLng(51.606163, -62.929688),
    bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'omniusnow.lcfl92fp', {
    // set that bounding box as maxBounds to restrict moving the map
    // see full maxBounds documentation:
    // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxbounds
    maxBounds: bounds,
    maxZoom: 16,
    minZoom: 5
});

// zoom the map to that bounding box
map.fitBounds(bounds);


var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

var geoJson = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-80.190583, 25.767619]
    },
    "properties": {
        "title": "Test location",
//this should let the button code know whether this is a development or a 
//land catagory, IT IS CASE SENSATIVE!!
   "Development":true,
   "Land":false,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Map-Markers-Icons-Demo-PNG/256/Map-Marker-Flag--Chartreuse.png",
            "iconSize": [50,50], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [50,50], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
   
        },
  'images': [
          ['http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Garfield_Building_Detroit.jpg','<p><b>Descriptive text goes here'],
          ['http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Greist_Building.JPG','More descriptive text goes here'],
          ['http://detroit1701.org/Graphics/Dime%20Building.jpg','A link to more info goes here']
        ]
  
    }
},{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-82.356899, 29.633012]
    },
    "properties": {
        "title": "Test location 2",
   "Development":false,
   "Land":true,
       "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Map-Markers-Icons-Demo-PNG/256/Map-Marker-Flag--Chartreuse.png",
            "iconSize": [50,50], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [50,50], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
   
        },
  'images': [
          ['http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Garfield_Building_Detroit.jpg','<p><b>Descriptive text goes here'],
          ['http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Greist_Building.JPG','More descriptive text goes here'],
          ['http://detroit1701.org/Graphics/Dime%20Building.jpg','A link to more info goes here']
        ]
  
    }

}];

// Set a custom icon on each marker based on feature properties.
myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var marker = e.layer;
    var feature = marker.feature;
  
    var images = feature.properties.images
    var slideshowContent = '';
 
marker.setIcon(L.icon(feature.properties.icon));
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var img = images[i];

        slideshowContent += '<div class="image' + (i === 0 ? ' active' : '') + '">' +
                              '<img src="' + img[0] + '" />' +
                              '<div class="caption">' + img[1] + '</div>' +
                            '</div>';
    }

    // Create custom popup content
    var popupContent =  '<div id="' + feature.properties.id + '" class="popup">' +
                            '<h2>' + feature.properties.title + '</h2>' +
                            '<div class="slideshow">' +
                                slideshowContent +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="cycle">' +
                                '<a href="#" class="prev">&laquo; Previous</a>' +
                                '<a href="#" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>' +
                            '</div>'
                        '</div>';

    // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup
    marker.bindPopup(popupContent,{
        closeButton: false,
        minWidth: 400
    });
 
});

        
// Add features to the map
myLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson)
.addTo(map);
//button stuff
$('.menu-ui a').on('click', function() {
    // For each filter link, get the 'data-filter' attribute value.
    var filter = $(this).data('filter');
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    markers.setFilter(function(f) {
        // If the data-filter attribute is set to "all", return
        // all (true). Otherwise, filter on markers that have
        // a value set to true based on the filter name.
        return (filter === 'Development') ? true : f.properties[filter] === true;
    });
    return false;
});
//end button stuff
$('#map').on('click', '.popup .cycle a', function() {
    var $slideshow = $('.slideshow'),
        $newSlide;

    if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
        $newSlide = $slideshow.find('.active').prev();
        if ($newSlide.index() < 0) {
            $newSlide = $('.image').last();
        }
    } else {
        $newSlide = $slideshow.find('.active').next();
        if ($newSlide.index() < 0) {
            $newSlide = $('.image').first();
        }
    }

    $slideshow.find('.active').removeClass('active').hide();
    $newSlide.addClass('active').show();
    return false;
});

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is my code without custom markers but with filters working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Multiple filters on markers</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.7/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.7/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.menu-ui {
  background:#A2A19F;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:50px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-110px;
  z-index:1;
  border-radius:3px;
  width:auto;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  }
  .menu-ui a {
    font-size:22px;
    color:#fff;
    display:table-cell;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    text-align:center;
    }
    .menu-ui a:first-child {
      border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
      }
    .menu-ui a:last-child {
      border:none;
      border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
      }
    .menu-ui a:hover {
      background:#f8f8f8;
      color:#404040;
      }
    .menu-ui a.active,
    .menu-ui a.active:hover {
      background:#DB3E3A;
      color:#FFF;
      }
  
</style>

<!-- jQuery is required for this example. -->
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>

<nav class='menu-ui'>
  <a href='#' class='active' data-filter='Development'>Development</a>
  <a href='#' data-filter='Land'>Land</a>
</nav>
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoib21uaXVzbm93IiwiYSI6ImFlZ0pNSXMifQ.VNyOy9GaRZ1cAS2nDTp3tw';
var southWest = L.latLng(21.284438,-131.265625),
    northEast = L.latLng(51.606163, -62.929688),
    bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
var geojson = [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-80.190583, 25.767619]
        },
        "properties": {
            "title": "Test location",
    //this should let the button code know whether this is a development or a 
    //land catagory, IT IS CASE SENSATIVE!!
       "Development":true,
       "Land":false,
        "marker-size": "large",
        "marker-symbol": "city"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-82.356899, 29.633012]
        },
        "properties": {
            "title": "Test location 2",
       "Development":false,
       "Land":true,
        "marker-size": "large",
        "marker-symbol": "city"
      }
    },
   
];


var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'omniusnow.lcfl92fp', {
    // set that bounding box as maxBounds to restrict moving the map
    // see full maxBounds documentation:
    // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxbounds
    maxBounds: bounds,
    maxZoom: 16,
    minZoom: 5
});

// zoom the map to that bounding box
map.fitBounds(bounds);

var markers = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
    .setGeoJSON(geojson)
    .addTo(map);

$('.menu-ui a').on('click', function() {
    // For each filter link, get the 'data-filter' attribute value.
    var filter = $(this).data('filter');
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    markers.setFilter(function(f) {
        // If the data-filter attribute is set to "all", return
        // all (true). Otherwise, filter on markers that have
        // a value set to true based on the filter name.
        return (filter === 'all') ? true : f.properties[filter] === true;
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I feel like I'm missing something small(maybe just syntax) but my lack of experience and knowledge with this language is preventing me from finding it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your not-working code listing, line 204, change `markers.setFilter(function(f) {` to `myLayer.setFilter(function(f) {`.

Comment: Just got the ability to up vote, thought I'd say thanks one more time.